# How to find source js file of network request in Firefox?

Tags: networking, firefox

We all know that we can see all the network requests at the network tab of Firefox. However, I don't see which script or file is sending the request. For example, I would like to know that foo.js is acquired due to explicit  in the html file. Or music.mp3 is acquired due to request from foo.js. How can I find the source of request?

Comment: Look at the source code or use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I have took the current page as an example and checked in **Firefox** browser with **Fire bugger** enabled . And then moved to **Net tab** under which chose **Javascript** tab. From where i can many **Get** requests being posted nearby which it mentions the js file from where the request is triggered.

Say for example

```
GET Quant.js
GET beacon.js
```